TypeError: HuggingFaceLLM.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hf_token'
LLM = HuggingFaceLLM(
    hf_token= os.getenv("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"),
    context_window=4096,
    max_new_tokens=256,
    generate_kwargs={"temperature": 0.0, "do_sample": False},
    system_prompt=system_prompt,
    query_wrapper_prompt=query_wrapper_prompt,
    tokenizer_name="meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf",
    model_name="meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf",
    device_map="auto",
    # uncomment this if using CUDA to reduce memory usage
    model_kwargs={"torch_dtype": torch.float16 , "load_in_8bit":True}
)

This is the error I'm receiving: TypeError: HuggingFaceLLM.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hf_token'
I have upgraded to the latest hugging face as well.

Why is your environment variable named hf_sIKvZj... ? That should be the value, and the name should be something like HF_TOKEN. If it's a private token, disable it and use a new one since you've posted yours publicly.

should i type in HF_TOKEN instead of my token in this space? hf_token= os.getenv("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")

Yes, that line should be something like hf_token= os.getenv("HF_TOKEN") and then you should have an environment variable called HF_TOKEN which has the value hf_sIKvZ.... That's not related to your error, I'm just referring to better security practices and not putting passwords/private tokens in code.

HuggingFaceLLM doesn't have hf_token or token as a parameter. But HuggingFaceInferenceAPI does have token as a param.
